# Trigonometry - Rotating an object to face away from a line

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, trigonometry

Basically I have two 2D points and there is a line between them. A cube is placed on the midpoint of this line. I want the cube to rotate so it is facing upwards from the line as the diagram below indicates.

[image: Illustrative diagram showing cubes on lines]

I've been thinking through how I can do this using trig and I still haven't come up with anything. Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo-code:

```
angle = atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)

cube.rotation = angle + PI/2
```

Answer (score 0):

Given two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), the angle of the line is given by

```
atan2(y2-y1, x2-x1)
```

Then rotate the square accordingly.  To do that you can use a Affine transform -- see

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
CGPointApplyAffineTransform
```

Here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html